# Why is a std::move of a value from a const std::optional possible?

Tags: c++, stdoptional, stdmove

Why is the following snippet legal C++ code? This is a purely theoretical question - there is no usecase that I have in mind:

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    const std::optional<std::vector<int>> ov = v;
    const auto nv = std::move(ov.value());

    for (const auto& x : *ov) { std::cout << x; }
    for (const auto& x : nv) { std::cout << x; }
}
```

This yields `123123`, but I do not understand the reason.

1. Why is a `std::move` applied to a value of a `const optional` legal?
2. Why does the `optional ov` still hold the `vector`?

Does `ov.value()` internally create a copy to a temporary which is then moved from?

Comment: Think of std::move() as a cast that does nothing for const objects. Nothing is moved here.

Comment: Note that since the move constructor of vector takes an non-const rvalue ref, the construction of nv is done using the _copy_ constructor.

Comment: When using `std::move`, I like to follow a policy that the object moved from is in a valid-but-unspecified state (suitable for re-assignment or destruction).  In general.  In the OP code, since `ov` is `const`, the `std::move` will **not** result in the object being gutted and left behind with an empty husk.  Regardless, I find following the idiom that the (potentially) moved-from object is as-if it were an ex-parrot works well.  In general.  (There are exceptions, such as moving from a `std::unique_ptr` does leave it in a well specified state.)

Comment: `std::vector<T>` is also an exception - a moved-from vector is guaranteed to be empty.

Comment: @Evg That's not an exception.  empty is a fine example of a valid-but-unspecified state.

Comment: @MooingDuck This makes no sense. Empty is a perfectly specified state. Otherwise, after doing `std::vector::clear()` the resulting vector would have been useless.

Comment: @Evg: Moving in general leaves objects in a valid but unspecified state, because moving objects in general can't make specific claims about every possible class you might write.  However, almost every class in the C++ standard library does specify a state for that specific class, which is usually but not always the "empty" state.

Comment: For `std::vector<T>` it is always an empty state.

Answer (score 18):

> Why is std::move applied to a value of a const optional legal?

Sure, why not? All that `std::move` is, is a cast to an rvalue reference. You'll just end up with an rvalue reference to a `const` object. That's nothing unusual.

> Why does the optional ov still holds the vector?

Because it is `const`, and cannot be changed.

Several conditions must happen in order for an object to be moved. `std::move` takes care of the most important one, but all others must be satisfied as well.

It is a common misconception that spraying `std::move` everywhere guarantees a super-duper-efficient move of an object from one place to another, by magic. That's not true, that's not what `std::move` is, it's just a cast that's sometimes needed in order to move something. But that's not everything that's needed, just the most important part.

Comment: This answer is correct, but seems to try hard to avoid saying the obvious thing: `move` is a misnomer, so its users should ignore the name when trying to remember what this function actually does.

Comment: I would argue that a "rvalue reference to a const object" is "something unusual", a rvalue reference generally represents an object that is ok to plunder, but a const object cannot be plundered.

Comment: You emphasise (by repeating twice) that `std::move` is not everything that's needed for a move, but can you name the other things that are needed? A link to a reference would be sufficient.